# Sorting of mysql data based on a field value

Tags: mysql

**This is the query I have**

```
SELECT p1.*, COUNT(p2.id) AS before_me_same_priority 
FROM priorities AS p1
LEFT JOIN priorities AS p2 ON p1.priority = p2.priority AND p1.id > p2.id
GROUP BY p1.id
ORDER BY before_me_same_priority, priority
;
```

**What I want to achieve is:**
What I need is One data with priority 1 first and then One with priority 2 and then priority 3 and then when there is no more data with any other priority it should be repeated again as priority 1 and 2 and 3 etc etc etc.

[image]

The Above Query works perfect, BUT as I have more than 30k data in the table the query stucks and loads in more than 10-15 mins. can we do something more faster?

**Desired**

[image]

> I have primary on ID and Priority. Still query is very slow.

Comment: do you have an index/key on the priority field ? and also on P2.id. it usually helps

Comment: show an EXLAIN of the query and a SHOW CREATE TABLE for all tables involved

Comment: I don't see how that table says anything useful.  Is it the input table?  Or the desired result?  We need to see both.l

Comment: MySQL 8.0 can do your task more simply with an `OVER()` clause and no `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

you should create an index (or a key) on the priority field.
same for p2.id if its not already the case

Comment: i tried that, there is primary on priority and id. Still takes very long.

Answer (score 0):

An index on the priority field will help.  A two column index on priority and id, in that order, will help even more.

Comment: i tried that, there is primary on priority and id. Still takes very long.